# I am an eight letter word. What am I?

Tags: riddle, word

> I am one of the oldest in the world, but oldest in India.
>
> I am one of the main resources for the Back Bone of India.
>
> I am a word with eight letters.

Clue is

> the opposite of 'SANE' and reverse the word.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I think the answer is

> [Kallanai](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kallanai_Dam)

I am one of the oldest in the World, but oldest in India.

> Kallanai is listed as the fourth oldest dam in the world and the oldest in India still in use.

I am one of the main resource for Back Bone of India.

> The backbone of India is agriculture. The purpose of the Kallanai is to divert the waters of the Kaveri across the fertile delta region for irrigation via canals.

Clue

> The antonym of 'sane' could be 'mad' which, when reversed, becomes 'dam'.